# How to make push notification's cube rotating view appear when app is in foreground?

Tags: ios, push-notification, uilocalnotification

How to make a cube rotating animation over status bar like push notification do?
Or how to make push notification displayed in iOS apps?

Like this:

[image]

Special thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there's any way to manually display the native iOS notification within the same app. You're going to have to ovverride:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
 didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
```

And then manually display your own view to dropdown from the top of the window by pulling `[userInfo objectForKey:@"alert"]` or whatever you have being sent with your push notification. You can create your own to mimic the iOS notification style or use a 3rd party dropdown view library like [YRDropdownView](https://github.com/onemightyroar/YRDropdownView) (or many others).

Answer (score 1):

From the `UILocalNotification` documentation:

> If the application is foremost and visible when the system delivers the notification, no alert is shown, no icon is badged, and no sound is played. However, the application:didReceiveLocalNotification: is called if the application delegate implements it. The UILocalNotification instance is passed into this method, and the delegate can check its properties or access any custom data from the userInfo dictionary.

Sounds like you'll have to implement the `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` method and create your own custom 'cube' there.

Comment: after all, i made my own notification cube at github: https://github.com/OpenFibers/OTNotification thanks